# how to invite same user multiple times using devise invitable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, devise-invitable

I am working with devise invitable gem with rails 3.2 application . My problem is that

I have a user who involves in several groups , so group owner will send invitation to that user . Now I want to implement the functionality to send invitation for the same user from different groups , but devise invitable not allows me to do that ..

Can anyone help me .. thanks in advance ..

Comment: Show what you have tried and you might get help easily :)

Comment: Looking for same solution - have you been able to resolve this?

Comment: no xander , still I did not find proper solution , I think I am stupid , though I know devise not allow us to create duplicate user , still I am trying  solution with devise ..

Comment: I'm in the same boat but it seems like devise-invitable isn't the right solution for invitations to groups: https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/issues/35   I'm investigating adding CanCan per the answer below.

Answer (score -6):

Devise is an authentication framework. Authentication only handles identifying who somebody is.

If you have a system where a user can get invited to multiple groups, then this is no longer authentication. Instead you need an authorization layer to manage what sort of access each user has.

You would still use Devise to log users into and out of your system but you need to use something like [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) in order to implement this sort of access control.

Comment: thanks for your reply .. I am using both devise and devise-invitable gems . devise for authentication and devise-invitable for sending invitation .

So my requirement is sending invitations for the same user from different groups using devise-invitable , the general mechanism devise invitable gem follows is it creates new user when user get invited .. So I think you are clear about my question .

Thanks